# Google Sheets Query Returns Abnormal Result After Changing Sheet Name

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet which i share with some users. They enter data at first sheet. I use their data at second, using query:

```
query('First Page'!A3:N;"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N where A = date '"&TEXT(TODAY();"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

This was returning todays data as expected, such as:

```
First Row (where i put formula): 'todays date' value value value ...
```

I had to delete 'First Page' because of certain problems. Then I have created an 'Entry Page' and modified my query:

```
query('Entry Page'!A3:I;"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I where A = date '"&TEXT(TODAY();"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

Now it returns:

```
First Row (where i put formula): previous dates (all  in one cell, seperated by space)
Second Row: 'todays date' value value value ...
```

Why this would happen? Why does it return irrelevant results?

Comment: I have turned back to a previous version and modified sheet name there, now it works as it supposed to. But still...

Answer (score 0):

Third parameter of query function proved essential here, by making it 0 i have solved my problem:

```
query('Entry Page'!A3:I;"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I where A = date '"&TEXT(TODAY();"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'";0)
```